# Setting content in init of ObjectController

Tags: ember.js

http://jsbin.com/onikid/3/edit

Can someone please tell me why `content` isn't persisting from overriden `init` call? If I set `content` in `setupController` it works fine, but that's not something I want to do, since I can use this controller from multiple routes and I would have to initialize it in all 'child' routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is saved but gets overridden by ember again. The following code is run by a route during setup [(Link to Ember Source)](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L112). When this function is called in your case, contex is unefined. Therefore the content (model is an alias) of your controller is set to undefined.

```
setup: function(context) {
    this.redirected = false;
    this._checkingRedirect = true;

    this.redirect(context);

    this._checkingRedirect = false;
    if (this.redirected) { return false; }

    var controller = this.controllerFor(this.routeName, context);

    if (controller) {
      this.controller = controller;
      set(controller, 'model', context);
    }

    if (this.setupControllers) {
      Ember.deprecate("Ember.Route.setupControllers is deprecated. Please use Ember.Route.setupController(controller, model) instead.");
      this.setupControllers(controller, context);
    } else {
      this.setupController(controller, context);
    }

    if (this.renderTemplates) {
      Ember.deprecate("Ember.Route.renderTemplates is deprecated. Please use Ember.Route.renderTemplate(controller, model) instead.");
      this.renderTemplates(context);
    } else {
      this.renderTemplate(controller, context);
    }
  },
```

So your requirement may not be fulfillable, since the content of your controller will always be set to the passed context.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand why - it looks like in ember philosophy model should be resolved by routing system using `setupController` or `serialize`/`deserialize` and not by the controller itself.